# install.packages function does not recognize new library path in RStudio

Tags: r, filepath, install.packages

I am connecting remotely to a work server and need to be able to install R packages via RStudio. I have read through other questions/answers on this topic, but haven't been able to solve this for myself. I think the following input and output shows my issues the best: (edit: I do not have admin powers, but can call IT as last resort)

```
>.libPaths("C:/RWorkSpace") #setting new file path
>.libpaths() #testing

[1] "C:/RWorkSpace"                      "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library"

>install.packages("bibliometrix", dependencies = TRUE, lib="C:/RWorkSpace") 

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\cortiz\AppData\Local\Temp\7\RtmpOsVuTB\downloaded_packages’

>library(bibliometrix)

Error in library(bibliometrix) : There is no package called 'bibliometrix'

>installed.packages()["bibliometrix","C:/RWorkSpace"]

Error in installed.packages()["bibliometrix","C:/RWorkSpace"] : subscript out of bounds
```

I just need to download the package and dependencies, and I expected them to be downloaded to the folder I specified ("C:/RWorkSpace").

- very new to working with R in general so please bear with me. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying that `c:\Users\cortiz\...` is different from `c:/RWorkSpace`, so something must be wrong? Realize that files are downloaded into a temporary location before attempting to actually install them in the correct location.

Comment: After that `downloaded` message, were there any warnings or errors? Did you try `library("bibliometrix")` before assuming it failed? If you type in `installed.packages()["bibliometrix","LibPath"]` (that's all one line/call, unbroken), what does it say?

Comment: That "downloaded" path is just a temp path where the package is unpacked. After it's successfully built, it will be copied into your libPath. I'm not sure you can change the temp file path used. That's controlled by the OS I think.

Comment: Hard-coded into `install.packages(.)` is the line `file.path(tempdir(), "downloaded_packages")`, which is where the temp-directory is retrieved. Since it's using `tempdir`, it can be influenced by environment variables `TMPDIR`, `TMP`, and `TEMP` (which can be set within R, in the relevant `.Renviron` or `.Rprofile` files, or user- or system-wide ... much of that is outside the scope of this question).

Comment: @r2evans, I did not realize loading packages worked in this way, thank you for explaining. No I am not simply assuming, naturally I have tried many times with different variations. I have edited my post to be more transparent.

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you. Perhaps I cannot load in packages if the temp path is located off the server? What might you try if you had administrative access?